# How to make askew slope image(b2body) in Box2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, chipmunk

I am new in Box2d and learning myself.
I am learning Box2d from [here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972)

I want to make a body and want to give b2body a angle so that it will look like body is stand like skew line, like slope.

This is my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    static int padding=20;

    // Create block and add it to the layer
    CCSprite *block = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"slope.png"];
    int xOffset = padding+block.contentSize.width/2+ ((block.contentSize.width+padding)*i);
    block.position = ccp(xOffset, 250);
    block.tag = 2;
    [self addChild:block];

    // Create block body
    b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
    blockBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;   //b2_dynamicBody
    blockBodyDef.position.Set(xOffset/PTM_RATIO, 250/PTM_RATIO);
    blockBodyDef.userData = block;
    b2Body *blockBody = _world->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);

    // Create block shape
    b2PolygonShape blockShape;
    blockShape.SetAsBox(block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2,
                        block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);

    // Create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef blockShapeDef;
    blockShapeDef.shape = &blockShape;
    blockShapeDef.density = 10.0;
    blockShapeDef.friction = 0.0;
    blockShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockShapeDef);            
}
```

In this code I made 4  b2body horizontically.  Now I want these in vertical and slightly skew, like a slope.

I am not able to do this yet.

I dont know I have to give angel to the body or something else. Not able to find sample code and good tutorials of Box2d.

Is there any site available where I can find some xcode Box2d demo for beginners?
Or some code like applications we have UIButtons, UILabel, UITextfiled programatically, can I find Box2d codes like this?

In this demo I am trying to make 4 static slope image and from the left upper side corner I have to push ball(b2dynamicbody). The ball will go through these 4 static body and the ball will turn according to the slope.

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: Can't you use a simple line as png and set the angle of your box ?

Comment: Sir I don`t have any experience in Box2d. This is my first demo.

Comment: Have you tried setting blockBodyDef.angle ?

Comment: um... for example, blockBodyDef.angle = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code in your sample and get a sloppy body

```
// Create block body
b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
blockBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;   //b2_dynamicBody
blockBodyDef.position.Set(200/PTM_RATIO, 250/PTM_RATIO);
blockBodyDef.userData = block;
b2Body *blockBody = _world->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);

// Create block shape
b2PolygonShape blockShape;

int num = 3;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(-27.5f / PTM_RATIO, -296.6f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-14.3f / PTM_RATIO, -127.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-281.0f / PTM_RATIO, -288.4f / PTM_RATIO)
};
blockShape.Set(verts, num);

// Create shape definition and add to body
b2FixtureDef blockShapeDef;
blockShapeDef.shape = &blockShape;
blockShapeDef.density = 10.0;
blockShapeDef.friction = 0.0;
blockShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockShapeDef);
```

Good luck, feel free to ask your queries.

Comment: what is block sir?    blockBodyDef.userData = block;  Error use of undeclared Identifier.

Comment: its sprite object, if you dont want to add sprite in body, just comment that line

Comment: Thanks aloot, Sir One more thing, I know how to create body but I dont know how to give colour to the body, like imgView.backgroundcolor = [uicolor redcolor]; , if we don't want to use .png image on imageview, Like this how to create body with color only not want to use .png image, for testing purpose?

Comment: you can not give color to body, its not supported in box2d, you have to use sprite with image only the option.

Comment: Thanks sir, Any good book or site for box2d where I can learn and get the sample code or some demo projects. I am completely beginner and till now it seem very difficult to me. Because I search on the internet and unable to find my queries until and unless I ask questions here and get answered from experts.

Comment: here is a manual for [box2d](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) and tutorials for the same is available [here](www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) in 'Game Physics' Section. there is no much material available for it. you will have to reveal stuffs from different languages code and change accordingly. though if you find any difficulty mail me the problem. i will try my best to solve it

Comment: Thanks Aloot sir. Definitely I am going to mail you. I am trying hard and I wont quit. Thank You so much once again.

Comment: Sir how to give this line  blockBodyDef.angle = 45 degree;  like this?

Comment: blockBodyDef.angle = 45/PTM_RATIO

Comment: Remember Box2D uses radians for angles, not degrees.